# How do I create a git repo on my shared hostgator?

Tags: git, repository

How do I create a git repo on my shared hostgator? 
Got SSH access by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming Git is installed...

```
git init --bare /path/to/repo
```

If Git isn't installed, you won't be able to push directly to the hosted repository, but you can make a snapshot available by doing the following (from [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#exporting-via-http)):

First, on your local machine, run these commands (this assumes your repo is at `~/foo` locally):

```
git clone --bare ~/foo ~/foo.git
cd ~/foo.git
git --bare update-server-info
```

Then, copy the resulting `foo.git` directory into your webserver's `public_html` directory. After doing so, you should be able to pull from the http://yourserver.com/you/foo.git or the like. Any time you want to update the snapshot, you'd need to repeat the above steps.

Comment: hmm..what u mean assuming git is installed? i have a git client only

Comment: You'd need to have Git installed on the server that you're creating a repo on as well.

Comment: Amber, what basically I want to do is: I already have a bitbucket private repo. I am using it on two machines. but sometimes i want it to go live on my username/public_html/repo_live ...how do i do that.. be specific please...

Comment: If you don't have `git` available on the remote machine, you can follow the directions here on your *local* machine, and then just copy the `.git` directory into somewhere in your `public_html` after doing so: http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#exporting-via-http

Comment: You'd probably use `scp` or a similar utility.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8605/discussion-between-amber-and-ali-gajani)