# Want to use sourcetree to monitor my online website and update my code

Tags: git

I am trying so many solution for solve this problem. This scenario is, i have a hostgator hosting and i want to use git(Source tree) to clone my project down. Therefore, when i change those files, i can check back and after push it will update on the site.
http://www.arlocarreon.com/blog/git/push-git-repo-into-shared-hosting-account-like-hostgator/ 
[How do I create a git repo on my shared hostgator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593183/how-do-i-create-a-git-repo-on-my-shared-hostgator)
I have try these method, add my machine RSA key into hosting. But my real problem is cant download it. Is that possible to clone it and when push it will update the website?

I get few error:

```
$ git clone --bare ****@******.com:public_html/.git
Cloning into bare repository 'public_html.git'...
Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

```
 $ git clone ssh:// ****@******:public_html/
    Cloning into 'public_html'...
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname  ****@******:public_html: Name or service not known
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Does anyone solve before this question? Or is not possible to use it on sourcetree?

Answer (score 0):

What type of hosting do you have?

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/how-do-i-get-and-use-ssh-access#connect

1. You need to create a SSH connection from source tree to host gator in order to pull/push to repositories in your hostgator account.

`ssh -p 2222 cpanelusername@cpanelipaddress` I'm on a mac.

2. create a id_rsa in the .ssh folder on your local machine. Remember and write down the passphrase!